# How to compare two IDs of different objects in testing?

Tags: lookup, validation, criteria-filter

Getting a failure error after running the test class...

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.: [Region__c]
```

Comment: Hi @CH Naveen Kumar, you should give more information. It looks like that you have a filter in a look up relationship that you are populating. Could you check it? To Help you, we need more info, like source code and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You receive that error because the lookup field *Region__c* has a lookup filter that prevents entering not valid values. You need to check the criteria of that filter (go to Setup -> Object Manager -> Your Object -> Region field)  and adjust you test class accordingly to set the valid value.